# How to hide "Share option" and take user directly to the "Save to Files" Screen in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, controller, share

I have gone through different stackoverflow questions or developer's forums but I am unable to find any answer.

The questions previously asked is about **previewing** files and then hiding the **Share** button on the **right top** of your screen.

Whereas, my question is related to using `UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate` and only allowing user to perform one action i.e. `Save to Files`

Currently, **this** popup opens which gives me option to `Share and Save to Files`
[image: Share and Save to Files]

Whereas, I want my `controller` to directly navigate to **this** screen:

[image]

I have written following code:

```
    func openUrl(url : URL) {
    self.documentInteractionController = UIDocumentInteractionController(url: url)
    self.documentInteractionController.delegate = self
    ProgressIndicator.hideHud()
    let isValidAppAvailable = self.documentInteractionController.presentOpenInMenu(from: self.view.frame, in: self.view, animated: true)
    
    if (!isValidAppAvailable){
        AlertManager.showAlert(self.getMessage(messageId: Messages.noCompatibleApplicationFound.rawValue))
    }
}
```

Any help on how to directly open `Save to Files` from code would be appreciated.

Comment: You can’t determine how the user will share/save the file. Even if you could all  he would need would be an extra step to do so.

Comment: Actually there are two buttons in my application, i.e. Download and Share. So when user taps on Download Button i only want to open FileManager and ask for location.